# ¿Cómo hacer que una función dé clic después de que el resultado esperado es true?

Tags: javascript

Hice la siguiente función la cual me hace una consulta en telegram web.
La consulta me la hace a un grupo `X` para ver si hay una nueva notificación en dicho grupo, si es `true` quiero que le dé clic y si es `false` que siga consultando cada 5 segundos.
Cuando hago la prueba si hay una notificación nueva me arroja `true` pero no da clic y si es `false` sigue consultando.
Necesito que cuando sea `true` dé clic.

Más abajo dejo el código.

```js
function getFolderName() {
  let folderName = document.querySelector("#folders-container > div > div.chatlist-top.has-contacts > ul > a:nth-child(1) > div.user-caption > p.dialog-subtitle > div");
  if (folderName) {
    console.log("folderName: ", folderName.textContent);
    // si folderName es true entonces que de click en el boton de la carpeta
    document.querySelector("#folders-container > div > div.chatlist-top.has-contacts > ul > a:nth-child(1) > div.user-caption > p.dialog-subtitle > div").click();
  } else {
    console.log("folderName: ", folderName);
    setTimeout(getFolderName, 5000);
  }
}
getFolderName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hazlo así, donde usamos `new Event` para crear el evento que luego lanzamos con [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) sobre el objeto deseado.  [Aquí mas información](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events):

```js
function getFolderName() {
  let folderName = document.querySelector("#folder-name");
  if (folderName) {
    console.log("folderName: " + folderName.textContent);
    boton = document.querySelector("#boton")
    const event = new Event('click');
    boton.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    console.log("folderName: ", folderName);
    setTimeout(getFolderName, 5000);
  }
}
getFolderName();
```

```html
<div id="folder-name">El nombre de la carpeta</div>
<button id="boton" onclick="alert('¡Hasta aquí hemos llegado!')">
Botón
</button>
```